# How to use the verb "assume" in the following situation?

Tags: verb-usage

I am a secret agent pretending to be Donald Trump.

Which is the correct way to express that using the verb "assume"?

1. I assume Donald.
2. I assume the name of Donald.
3. I assume the name "Donald".
4. I assume the identity of Donald.

Comment: did you mean *"If I were Donald Trump, I would ... "*?

Comment: No, I mean something like "I pretend to be Donald Trump when playing with kids".

Comment: It's not the grammar that's a problem, but the vocabulary. If you assume a name, you begin to use it as your official name. You can 'assume the identity' of another person, but that means something more than just pretending to be them for a short time. You could say "I impersonate Donald Trump".

Comment: Ok, thanks for vocabulary, but actually I don't care much about context and vocabulary. The thing I need is to know if my sentences are correct. Let's imagine I am a secret agent pretending to be Donald Trump.

Comment: Isn't it weird to _assume the persona_ of Donald Trump when playing with kids? Unless you mean in a play-scary way, like _pretending to be_ the Big Bad Wolf?

Comment: @ Michael Harvey, I need to know how to use "assume", but not when to use it. Is it necessary to put "the persona" in the sentence? Can I say simply "I assume Donald" or "I assume the name Donald"?

Comment: Have you tried looking at meanings of "assume" in a good dictionary such as Cambridge, Oxford, Merriam-Webster? If you have, what did you not understand?

Comment: If you'd like your question reopened, please clarify it by including more details and scenarios you'd like to use the word in. You should do a dictionary look-up first and, if your question is not answered by a dictionary, tell us why the dictionaries fail to answer your question.

Comment: From what I see in Cambridge Dictionary, they put an object after "assume" so I suppose that I can put  a name (an object) after the verb.

Comment: @Vova - you assume a thing. A role, a persona, a responsibility, a part (e.g. in a play). You can _assume the name [of] Vova_ but not _assume Vova_.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the verb 'assume' with just a name, if you want to talk about pretending to be, or acting as that person. You assume a role, a part (e.g. in a game or play), an identity etc. The verb needs an object (it is transitive).

Comment: Finally you understand what I need. The phrase "to assume Mickey Mouse" is incorrect, ok. What about "to assume the name of Mickey Mouse" and "to assume the name Mickey Mouse"?